# How to solve migration problem in sugar crm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a problem in my work that when i migrate my sugarcrm system from 5.5 version to 6.2 version i am not able to get the delete, edit icon images in the dashlet and not able to get the drag option in the dashlet. please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your dashlets restricted. In ADMIN-->System Settings look to see if user editable dashlets is checked. This would make it so you can't drag the dashlet. The edit, refresh, delete option will appear when you move your cursor over the menu bar of the dashlet itself.